# Simultaneous special orthogonal similarity problem

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, orthogonal-groups, similarity

Given matrices $A,B,C,D\in\Bbb K^{n\times n}$ where $\Bbb K$ is a ring is there an efficient technique to compute set $O$ with $OO'=I$ where $'$ is transpose and $\mathsf{Det}(O)=\pm1$ such that 
$$A=OCO'$$
$$B=ODO'$$
holds?

Comment: I suggest to add the "number theory" tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, which may efficiently show lack of solution in some cases.

Make square matrix $O$ with entries variables. We have $O'=O^{-1}$
and $O'$ is the transpose.

Mulitply by $O'$. Since $OO'=I$ we get:

$O'A=CO',O'B=DO'$.

This is systems of $2n^2$ linear equations over $K$ in $n^2$ variables.

If the linear system doesn't have solution, there is no solution to the problem.

In addition we need the constraint $\det(O)=\pm 1$, which might be intractable to compute symbolically.

If the linear system doesn't have solution, there is no solution.

If $K$ is a field, find basis for the solutions and try to substitute
in the nonlinear constraint, searching for solution in it.

Comment: how do you know 'efficiently solvable'? I have $n^2/2$ variable at  a minimum and also are you claiming O is unique?

Comment: @Arul Yes, you have exactly n^2 variables, but the system is _linear_. If $K$ is a field, just compute basis of the big linear system. It might have infinitely many solutions. Ask about complexity of solving linear equations if you doubt "efficiently".

Comment: it seems to me that you are implying there are always infinite solutions

Comment: @Arul I didn't wrote this. Search the web for solutions of linear equations. There might no solution.

Comment: @Arul So far my answer is wrong. I need additional nonlinear constraint $det(O)=\pm$. If the linear system doesn't have solution, it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very poorly stated. Where are the necessary conditions linking the matrices $A,B,C,D$ ? We assume that $K$ is a commutative ring with unity.

$OO^T=I$ implies that $\det(O)^2=1$ and $\det(O)$ is  a unit, that implies that $O^T=O^{-1}$, $O^TO=I$ and $AB=OCDO^T$. Now $A=OCO^T$ over $\mathbb{C}$ means that $A,C$ are orthogonally similar, that is the object of the Specht theorem. Here the necessary part of this theorem is valid and can be written: $tr(W(A,A^T))=tr(W(C,C^T))$ for any word $W$ in two non-commuting variables. Similar relations link $(B,D)$, $(AB,CD)$ and also $(BA,DC)$. Moreover $A,C$ (resp. $B,D$) have same characteristic polynomial and, in particular, same determinant.

It remains to add the $2n^2$ joro's equations. Roll up your Sleeves.